Laravel 11.0 Session management in helper function
I made custom service functions at app/Helpers folder, called the function in controller. When pass the function, I would like to put session
I am using Laravel 11.0, And I wouldn't like to pass $request variable to function, I am wondering can I use
request()->session()->put()
instead of this
$request->session()->put()

Elaborate your question.Share your custom service function that you made in app/Helper.php.What it show if you use request()->session()->put()?Isn't it working the way you want it to be?

did you try using request()->session()->put()?

Thanks for your replay! I've tried with $request->session()->put() currently, but I wouldn't like to pass the request variable to function from controller, so I wanted confirm If I use request()->session()->put(), if it will work as like $request->session()->put()
